# how store base64 image on json serialize postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ionic2, hstore

guys, i have a JSON serialize images column for saving images, images type has a base64 encoding ( for more detail: on ionic 2 framework I converted the image to base64 encoding and send to server )

products table

```
t.column  :images, :string
```

product model

```
  mount_uploaders :images, ProductUploader
  serialize :images, JSON
```

now, how store base64 image on JSON serialize column?
I found this converter code for upload action but not working

```
def parse_image_data(base64_image)
filename = "upload-image"
in_content_type, encoding, string = base64_image.split(/[:;,]/)[1..3]

@tempfile = Tempfile.new(filename)
@tempfile.binmode
# for example i replace an image 
@tempfile.write "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
@tempfile.rewind

# for security we want the actual content type, not just what was passed in
content_type = `file --mime -b #{@tempfile.path}`.split(";")[0]

# we will also add the extension ourselves based on the above
# if it's not gif/jpeg/png, it will fail the validation in the upload model
extension = content_type.match(/gif|jpeg|png/).to_s
filename += ".#{extension}" if extension

ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({
  tempfile: @tempfile,
  type: content_type,
  filename: filename
})
end




  def clean_tempfile
    if @tempfile
      @tempfile.close
      @tempfile.unlink
    end
  end
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get errors? Do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: pleas visit my question title i write how store base64 image for example i write this code for save image but not working       @images=[]
      images.each do |image|
          @images.append(parse_image_data((image)))
      end  @product.image=@images @Wukerplank

Comment: It's not a good idea to store multiple images in one record. Otherwise you need no JSON serialize.

Comment: why not good idea ? i most create a model for image and build relation to product and this is not good idea @PavelMikhailyuk

Comment: You have created one column right in the `products` table to store **multiple** images in the question's example. Not relation. So it seems you are going to store **many** images just in one product's record. That I called "not good idea".